# Telerik MVC Grid - Format number to Indian display format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-mvc

I am struggling to get the Telerik MVC Grid to display number formatted according to Indian standards. Basically, I have a number, for example - 55555555555 and I want it to be displayed by Telerik MVC grid as 55,55,55,55,555. So I tried to use the pattern "##,##,##,##,###". This worked well for the above example. However, if I use 555555555 (two 5's less than the earlier example), then it displays as 555,555,555 instead of 55,55,55,555. I am not sure why this happens. 
How do I have a Telerik MVC grid display number according to Indian number formatting as mentioned at start?

Comment: Can't you use the Indian CultureInfo for this, rather than specifying the format string?  Come to think of it, why do you want the Indian format?  Because all of your users are Indian?  If some users might not be Indian, then perhaps you should use the user's culture.

Comment: @phoog, I have already set the culture to Indian and if I display a number in my web page using the format "{0:n0}" (not from telerik mvc grid) then the number is formatted correctly. However within Telerik MVC grid the format "{0:n0}" is not recognized and it just displays "n55555555555" instead of formatting the number. So I had to resort to custom formatting using # place holder. So in short, I can get the number formatting to work in Indian culture only outside of Telerik MVC grid. Within the grid I am still confused how to format the number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a jquery globalization plugin available at  https://github.com/jquery/globalize#format. That makes the task of formatting very easy particularly if the formatting is to be done at client side.

regards,
Nirvan.

Answer (score 1):

You can localize all values on the grid by setting the .Localizable("hi-IN") on the grid itself.

[Telerik MVC Grid Localization](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/grid/localization)

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but the grid doesn't recognize the format "{0:n0}". If I use "{0:n}" for the format instead, I still get number formatted by thousands separator and not the indian format. Anyways I cannot use the "{0:n}" because it displays decimals as well. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Another option is to do the formatting in the controller and passing the complete string to the grid.

Comment: Luke, formatting in controller would work, but I am a little confused with custom formatting using "#" and ",". It doesn't seem to work the obvious way. As indicated in my question why does "#" and "," not work. Custom formatting seems to me as the correct way of solving this problem and that's why I am inclined to use it. The only problem is that it doesn't work the way I expected.

Comment: If you format in the controller, you can use localization instead of custom formatting--value.ToString("n0", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("hi-IN"));

Comment: @Daniel, Even if I do the formatting in Controller, I cannot do the same for "Count" and "Sum" of Client Footer Template of Telerik Grid. Count and Sum are aggregates that are available only in the client side (i.e. javascript code). I can in no way format these in my controller. In short, I could format some values that I display using the Controller, but for some values (calculated by Telerik), I have no control over its formatting accept passing a format string to Telerik code.

Comment: @Nirvan, I agree, it is much better to have the formatting done client side. Were you able to get the jquery globalization plugin to work with the grid control?

Comment: @Daniel, Yes, I got it working for ajax bound telerik mvc grid.